# Restricting C++ code from accessing certain classes in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have two classes in a Java program. Class A and Class B.
Class B contains a native function that will execute C++ code.

As far as I know, the C++ code will run in the same process as the Java code.

The question that I have is that how can I limit the C++ code from accessing the Java memory and reading Class A's parameters?

[image: I want to protect Class A's Parameters from the C++ code]

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid you are out of luck. Unlike reflection, JNI is completely unsecurable: CallVoidMethod() or GetIntField() can access everything.

To a certain extent, obfuscation can help. If class A is obfuscated, human-readable names of all its fields and methods are gone. Usually obfuscators generate stable, predictable names, but with an easy [trick](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/111/) they can be randomized. Proguard can also 'optimize' your class, inlining some methods. Methods that don't exist anymore, cannot be called via JNI.

But still, the fields will be there, the methods that are called from 'outside' will still be there and maybe even preserve their names. So, better don't load a JNI library that you cannot trust into your process. Well, this is true for any DLL.